# Spring RestController - No converter found for return value of type java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring

I am currently trying to create my first **rest service with spring**, I wan't him to return **XML result (based on JAXB)**.

on a very basic rest controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CVIController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resume")
    public @ResponseBody
    Integer getResume() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

with a spring-servlet.xml pretty empty:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.urouen"
    />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

And a Tomcat server under JDK8 so I can be sure that all modules are load by default on the JVM... I got the following exception throwed:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.lang.Integer
```

I don't wan't to use Jackson because I know that JAXB can handle this.
But after juggle with some part of my code, I still can't found the answer of why she is throwed.

**Edit 1:**

I tried to create a dummy class with getters as answers said

```
public class Dummy {
    private int value;


    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@RestController
public class CVIController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resume")
    public ResponseEntity<Dummy> getResume() {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
        dummy.setValue(5);
        return new ResponseEntity<Dummy>(dummy, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But still got the exact same result :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class fr.urouen.model.Dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to return a String and remove the @ResponseBody annotation.  As a rest controller, by definition, returns a string,  that's the way to go for this specific example.

If you are after a more comprehensive solution, Spring by default uses Jackson to do the conversion from object to JSON.  The @ResponseBody does that automatically.

Im pretty sure that Integer won't work because it's not a POJO with getters and setters and something that can be converted to JSON.  ie { 5 }  is not a valid JSON object.

if you had a class like this:

```
public class returnObject() {
  private int value;
  ... getters/setters
}
```

and then did this:

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
public ReturnObject getValue() {
   ReturnObject ret = new ReturnObject();
   ret.setValue(5);
   return ret;
}
```

You would then get this:

```
{ "value" : 5 }
```

You will also need to add jackson to your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've try with classes simple as ReturnObject but it still doesn't works. If I'm returning a String, I am suppose to build her (with JAXBContext ect ?... Pretty uncomfortable for a Framework like that).

Comment: try adding <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> and <context:annotation-config /> to your xml.

Answer (score 0):

ResponseEntity is used for a return some content from restcontroller, Have you tried with `ResponseEntity` ?

```
@RestController
public class CVIController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resume")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getResume() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(5);
    }
}
```

or you can write

```
@RestController
public class CVIController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resume")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Integer> getResume() {
        return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(5, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

more example you can get from [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-response-entity.html)

Comment: Have you added any marshaling lib like Jackson or Gson ?

Comment: No because as I said, I don't wan't to use Jackson because I know that JAXB can handle this (like many online tutorial said)

Comment: For now I have a working solution with Jackson, but I would like to have the one with JAXB.

Comment: oky I read one blog https://www.admfactory.com/jaxb-hello-world-marshallingunmarshalling-example/, and there is not mentioned Integer class in data type, so that's the reason JAXB not understanding, try with BigInteger or just int as return type.

Comment: Or you can directly return java.lang.Object

Comment: I have tried with the dummy class in the post, why would she not be good ?

Answer (score 0):

I met this promblem too,try download jackson-databind.jar,ackson-core.jar, ackson-annotations.jar and put them in your WEB-INF/lib directory